# How to use awk to split files by separator and pipe into another script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I currently have a gawk program that does what I want:

```
gawk '{command = ("python gen.py")
    print $0 | command
    close(command)}' RS='*** END OF THE RECORD' bigfile.txt
```

Basically, I have a big file (think 1 gb) that has a couple hundred records, each split by a line that starts with "*** END OF THE RECORD". Each record chunk will be a few megabytes big, like ~5mb.

I'm splitting the file into small sections (separated by the "***END OF THE RECORD" line), and piping it into a python program to do further processing.

How can I do this in plain awk, not gawk? This program currently gives me an error in awk.

Notably, this program pipes each small output into another program, so solutions that output every line separately won't work. I also need to close the pipe with the `close(command)` so that a new script runs for each file I pipe.

I've tried something like this:

```
awk '/^*** END OF THE RECORD/{next}{command = ("python gen.py")
    print | command
    close(command)}' file.text
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me under GNU `awk --posix`.  Replace:

```
RS='*** END OF THE RECORD'
```

With:

```
RS='\\*\\*\\* END OF THE RECORD'
```

Or, better yet:

```
RS='[*][*][*] END OF THE RECORD'
```

The problem was that `RS` is treated as a regex and `***` is an illegal regex.

#### A Simpler Example

This simpler script generates the same error that I see in your longer script:

```
$ awk --posix '1' RS='*** END OF THE RECORD' file
awk: fatal: Invalid preceding regular expression: /*** END OF THE RECORD/
```

When the stars are escaped, the error disappears and the code runs with either of these:

```
$ awk --posix '1' RS='\\*\\*\\* END OF THE RECORD' file
$ awk --posix '1' RS='[*][*][*] END OF THE RECORD' file
```